# How to create a Sphere with World Map using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was making a sphere with world map using three.js but the output is just a black screen as shown.

[image: BlackScreen]

The code I used is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16 );
            const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Lines\land_ocean_ice_cloud_2048.jpg' );
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );           
            const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( sphere );



            function animate() 
            {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
                sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't explain why the code was unable to render the sphere. What went wrong?

Comment: Use an online image file: https://jsfiddle.net/j6xgembp/

Comment: Did you add the camera to the scene? See also https://barrycarter.github.io/pages/MAPS/bc-test-3d.html for an example

Comment: @BarryCarter If you replace the file system path with a proper URL, the code works as-is (the camera is used to render, it doesn't have to be added to the scene)

Comment: @ChrisG wooooah...I never thought that downloading the source and image from Internet and render it on web browser is impossible. The source and the image that should be rendered on web browser must be coming from the Internet itself and link it to the code via <source> and <texture> using Internet URL.

Comment: @BarryCarter wooooah...I never thought that downloading the source and image from Internet and render it on web browser is impossible. The source and the image that should be rendered on web browser must be coming from the Internet itself and link it to the code via <source> and <texture> using Internet URL.

Comment: You should always check the browser's console for errors. It says it can't load the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16 );
            const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.imgur.com/kFoWvzw.jpg' );
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );           
            const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( sphere );



            function animate() 
            {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
                sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I never thought that downloading the source and image from Internet and render it on web browser is impossible. The source and the image that should be rendered on web browser must be coming from the Internet itself and link it to the code via `<source>` and `<texture>` command using Internet URL.

What is more amazing is that once that the source and the image coming from the Internet via Internet URL has been rendered on web browser, it works even without any Internet!